# Данные какого типа возвращаются методом getMethodName()?(java)

Tags: java, stacktrace

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements)
    {
       System.out.println(element.getMethodName());
    }
```

---

**getMethodName** возвращает имя метода, который был вызван. Но какого **типа** это возвращаемое имя? Можно ли "положить" имена вызываемых методов в массив, чтобы потом их использовать? Если да, то как?

---

**Например**, целесообразно ли поступить таким образом

```
public static String[] method5() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        String[] names = new String[stackTraceElements.length];

        for(StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements){
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                names[i]=element.getMethodName();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Comment: [С виду обычный `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getMethodName()). Что мешает, собстна?

Comment: С виду да. Но вдруг нет? нигде не нашел нужной информации

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на документацию. Это ж Java, там типы практически у всего указываются в документации, т. к. это нужно для нормальной работы языка.